# I need help understanding how this algorithm that finds smallest value of an array using recursion works

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm currently taking data structures and am learning about recursions. The code/algorithm posted below is supposed to find the smallest value of an array using recursion. However, I'm having trouble understanding how it works. My teacher's explanation wasn't very helpful so if anyone knows how to explain this well I would really appreciate it!

```
public class Recursive {

    public static int minimum(int array[], int first, int last) {
        int answer;
        int mid;
        int minFirst;
        int minSecond;
        
        if(first == last)
            return array[first];
        else {
            mid = (first + last) / 2;
            minFirst = minimum(array, first, mid);
            minSecond = minimum(array, mid + 1, last);
        }
        if(minFirst < minSecond)
            answer = minFirst;
        else
            answer = minSecond;
        return answer;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method finds the minimum element in an array *in the range specified by* `first` and `last`. So `minimum(arr, 4, 6)` would find the minimum among `arr[4]`, `arr[5]` and `arr[6]`.

Let's see how it does this.

If `first` is the same as `last`, there is only one element in the specified range, and that is `array[first]` (or `array[last]`, which is the same thing). The smallest element must be that element, so return `array[first]`.

Otherwise, we want to split the range into two halves. To do this, we first find the mid point of the range by doing `(first + last) / 2` - calculating the average of `first` and `last`. Then the two halves are:

- from `first` to `mid`
- from `mid + 1` to `last`

Then we find the minimum element in each of those halves, hence:

- `minimum(array, first, mid)`
- `minimum(array, mid + 1, last)`

I understand that it's counterintuitive how we can use the `minimum` method when we haven't even finished declaring what it does, but let's trust ourselves that `minimum` will do what it's supposed to do - find the minimum between the ranged specified by the last two arguments.

Then we compare these minimums. Whichever of these minimums is smaller, is the minimum element in the whole range (what the last if statement is doing).

Comment: Thank you this cleared things up for me! And yes I was confused by the minimum(of first half) and minimum(of second half) as it didn't make sense how it was even finding it.

Answer (score 0):

To better understand how the code works, lets put some print statements. This will tell us what data each recursion of the method is working on.

 I've put some comments in code.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] arr = {4,3,2,1};
        System.out.println("\nThe smallest element is : " +minimum(arr, 0, 3, 1));
    }
    
    //this method finds smallest element within given range in an array
    public static int minimum(int array[], int first, int last, int indent) {
        //lets print what each recursion is working on
        int[] subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, first, last+1);
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(indent) + "Invoked with: first=" 
                    + first + " last=" + last 
                    + " Array=" + Arrays.toString(subArray));
        int answer;
        int mid;
        int minFirst;
        int minSecond;
        
        if(first == last) {
            System.out.println(" ".repeat(indent) + "Selected " + array[first]);
            return array[first];
        }
        else {
            //divide the range in half
            mid = (first + last) / 2;
            //find smallest element from first half
            minFirst = minimum(array, first, mid , indent + 3);
            //find smallest element from second half
            minSecond = minimum(array, mid + 1, last, indent +3);
        }
        
        //select smallest element from both halves
        if(minFirst < minSecond)
            answer = minFirst;
        else
            answer = minSecond;
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(indent) + "Selected " + answer + " from " + minFirst + ", " + minSecond);
        return answer;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
 Invoked with: first=0 last=3 Array=[4, 3, 2, 1]
    Invoked with: first=0 last=1 Array=[4, 3]
       Invoked with: first=0 last=0 Array=[4]
       Selected 4
       Invoked with: first=1 last=1 Array=[3]
       Selected 3
    Selected 3 from 4, 3
    Invoked with: first=2 last=3 Array=[2, 1]
       Invoked with: first=2 last=2 Array=[2]
       Selected 2
       Invoked with: first=3 last=3 Array=[1]
       Selected 1
    Selected 1 from 2, 1
 Selected 1 from 3, 1

The smallest element is : 1
```

You can also use [debug feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h12OUX0H-K4) of your IDE like Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you! This is similar to tracing the method right? My teacher went over a similar way but did by hand

Answer (score 0):

Just about every recursion algorithm consists of 2 crucial parts:

### The trivial case(s)

All recursive algorithms give an instantaneous answer (and do not recurse) for trivial input.

In this specific case, the trivial input case is when 'first' and 'last' are equal to each other: The intent of the method is to return the smallest value found amongst all values starting at index 'first' and ending at index 'last'. When first and last are equal, there is only one number to look at. Trivially then, 'what is the smallest number amongst this giant collection of.... 1 number', is.. that number. That is the trivial case.

### The progression towards the trivial case.

All other cases are resolved by first invoking your own method again, but with modified inputs - the inputs should be modified so that they have moved closer towards the edge case in some fashion. Sometimes, you invoke your own method multiple times, but *all* such invocations must *all* be guaranteed to be closer to the trivial case, and then you combine the separate answers.

In this case, the problem is stated as:

To find the smallest number from a list of numbers, first, lop the list of numbers into two roughly equal parts. These lists are smaller, and therefore, simpler, so we can just ask ourselves to calculate the answer for these smaller lists - that's okay, we moved them towards the trivial case, we can do that. Then, combine the two obtained answers: Just return the smallest answer, chunking out the larger one.

### That's it.

That's all you need to write recursive code. It makes sense if you think about it in these terms: For any input, the algorithm is to restate the problem in terms of a simple operation applied to the result of calculating a slightly simpler question.

The result of that slightly simpler question is done the same way: By applying a simple operation to the result of calculating an even simpler question.

Rinse and repeat until the question is so incredibly simple, the answer is obvious and can be provided immediately.

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense, I was overcomplicating it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Let's add more log, and you can see clearly:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Recursive {

    private static AtomicInteger step = new AtomicInteger();

    public static int minimum(int array[], int first, int last) {
        int answer;
        int mid;
        int minFirst;
        int minSecond;
        int currentStep = step.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println("=================== step: " + currentStep + "=============");
        int[] currentArray = new int[last - first];
        System.arraycopy(array, first, currentArray, 0, currentArray.length);
        System.out.println("current array(" + first + ", " + last + "): " + Arrays.toString(currentArray));
        System.out.print(String.format("first(%d) == last(%d): %b", first, last, first == last));
        if(first == last) {
            System.out.println(", so min = " + array[first]);
            return array[first];
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(", so divide 2 the array");
            mid = (first + last) / 2;
            minFirst = minimum(array, first, mid);
            int minFirstStep = step.get();
            minSecond = minimum(array, mid + 1, last);
            int minSecondStep = step.get();
            System.out.print(String.format("compare min of step[%d] and step[%d]: %d < %d = %b",
                                           minFirstStep,
                                           minSecondStep,
                                           minFirst,
                                           minSecond,
                                           minFirst < minSecond));
        }
        if(minFirst < minSecond)
            answer = minFirst;
        else
            answer = minSecond;
        System.out.println(", so min = " + answer);
        return answer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = {1, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2};
        int min = minimum(array, 0, array.length - 1);
        System.out.println("min is: " + min);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
=================== step: 1=============
current array(0, 5): [1, 4, 7, 8, 5]
first(0) == last(5): false, so divide 2 the array
=================== step: 2=============
current array(0, 2): [1, 4]
first(0) == last(2): false, so divide 2 the array
=================== step: 3=============
current array(0, 1): [1]
first(0) == last(1): false, so divide 2 the array
=================== step: 4=============
current array(0, 0): []
first(0) == last(0): true, so min = 1
=================== step: 5=============
current array(1, 1): []
first(1) == last(1): true, so min = 4
compare min of step[4] and step[5]: 1 < 4 = true, so min = 1
=================== step: 6=============
current array(2, 2): []
first(2) == last(2): true, so min = 7
compare min of step[5] and step[6]: 1 < 7 = true, so min = 1
=================== step: 7=============
current array(3, 5): [8, 5]
first(3) == last(5): false, so divide 2 the array
=================== step: 8=============
current array(3, 4): [8]
first(3) == last(4): false, so divide 2 the array
=================== step: 9=============
current array(3, 3): []
first(3) == last(3): true, so min = 8
=================== step: 10=============
current array(4, 4): []
first(4) == last(4): true, so min = 5
compare min of step[9] and step[10]: 8 < 5 = false, so min = 5
=================== step: 11=============
current array(5, 5): []
first(5) == last(5): true, so min = 2
compare min of step[10] and step[11]: 5 < 2 = false, so min = 2
compare min of step[6] and step[11]: 1 < 2 = true, so min = 1
min is: 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This is pretty clear I just have one question. For example, on one of the last lines (current array 5,5 or current array 3,5) what is that supposed to be because there is no 5th location in the array?

Comment: Hi, `array[] = {1, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2}` so current array(5, 5) = copy of the array form index 5th to 5th = [], current array (3, 5) = copy of the array from index 3rd to 5th = [8, 5]

Comment: Ohhh I see. Step 1 didn't have the 2 of fifth location but the main method did.